# Бесплатный переводчик апи

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Нужен бесплатный переводчик апи с англ. на русский, примерно 1000-3000 символов в месяц. Кто-нибудь может подсказать? Перепробовал много вариантов, много чего не работает или есть платные тарифы

Comment: Чем не устраивает yandex api? там вообще вроде бесплатно

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, давно уже платный стал, яндекс и гугл, начиная с 2020

Comment: https://www.deepl.com/ru/pro-api?cta=header-pro-api

Comment: [LibreTranslate](https://github.com/LibreTranslate/LibreTranslate) можете попробовать, только там нужно выбрать зеркало, где не требуется апи ключ.

Comment: @ΝNL993, а можете подсказать, что за зеркало?

Comment: @ΝNL993, видел этот апи, но насколько я понял, он раньше был без ключа, а сейчас ввели обязательно ключ

Comment: @Dragon `что за зеркало?` -- допустим [libretranslate.eownerdead.dedyn.io](https://libretranslate.eownerdead.dedyn.io)